# Problem with Convert.ToDateTime in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatting, web-config, culture

I have an application that works without any problem in a spanish server.

When i uploaded the application into the online server (an english windows), im getting exceptions (of type "input string is not a valid Datetime/Int32") with Convert.ToDateTime and Convert.ToInt32. Are any web.config line that could help me in this matter? I tried adding a globalization element with the Spanish culture, but didnt worked.

Could you give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.
Josema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = 
              new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
DateTime myDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(string, culture);
```

Comment: Hi ck, thanks for your fast answer, 

Are your lines the same than this?:


1º Put in a web config the Spanish culture

2º Datetime datetime=Convert.ToDatetime("01/2009");


Thanks.
Josema.

Comment: @Josema y, it will use the one in your web.config if you don't specify   one explicitly.

Comment: @Josema I assume this "Convert.ToDatetime("01/2009")" was just a typo and you have stuff like Convert.ToDateTime("31/01/2009")

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifying a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) argument, as an `IFormatProvider` in your [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) calls?

Answer (score 2):

You might have set uiculture instead of culture in the globalization element, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx.

```
...
    <globalization culture="es-MX" />
...
```

You can also try using a more specific culture (like the one above es - mexico).

Ps. I have a site working like that (actually with culture="en" as in my case I needed to force english as my development computer was configured with spanish at the time).

Comment: @Josema Try the variation with the more specific culture, specially given your scenario seemed to work when specifying it explicitely as in ck answer.