# unable to convert string to date in asp.net correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I unable to  convert string to date, my string like 17/12/2012 
Code written for this is shown below

```
public string Date_Convert(string dt1)
{
    string strdate = string.Empty;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt1);
    strdate = dt.Month.ToString() + "/" + dt.Day.ToString() + "/" + dt.Year.ToString();
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    return strdate;
}
```

It is working fine in my local system. And not working in my server(which is located at Australia)of course I tried with different culture settings in the above code,

I'm using this date string in sql query in where condition.

please help me, It killed my one day time, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Sql-Parameters instead to avoid sql-injection and issues like this. _"I'm using this date string in sql query in where condition.

"_

Comment: Any error message showing?

Comment: Do you get any exception, error ? because your current code for date `17/12/2012` should work just fine

Comment: Why don't you just use `ParseExact` much easier to use then changing the culture. Hard to help unless you tell us what is not working exactly and how its failing.  You might want to look at http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" and "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime." I'm getting these exception msg, I used Sql-Parameters as "Tim Schmelter" said but same problem, and thanks for many replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of switching the culture, why don't you do something like this:

```
public string Date_Convert(string dt1)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dt1, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
    return dt.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

Also: If you use the value in an SQL query (and provided that your query works on a `DATETIME` field, not `NVARCHAR`), you should also consider using a parameterized query to pass the `DateTime` value to the database to avoid SQL injection.

For example:

```
DateTime value = DateTime.Parse(dt1, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Date = @date", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", value);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not working* - do you get an Exception in the `Date_Convert` function or later when using the converted date as the parameter for the query? The Exception text *Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime* you provided in your comment to your question suggests that you're treating the parameter as a string in your query instead of actually using a parameter of type `datetime`. Are you calling a stored procedure that takes the date as an `nvarchar`? If so, change that parameter to `datetime` and use the code I provided.

Comment: I'm getting two exceptions as you specified above "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" and "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

Comment: At which point in the code? The first one seems to be thrown when you try to convert the `string` into a `DateTime` in `Date_Convert`. In this case, please update your question to show the exact input and how you're currently trying to parse the value. The second exception seems to be thrown when you try to pass the value to the database - please specify whether you pass in a `DateTime` as parameter (as I suggested) or another converted string (which is a bad idea and error-prone as you can see).

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. This is what I'm getting. with Date_convert function.public string Date_Convert(string dt1)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dt1, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
    return dt.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
} My Input string for dt1 is "19/12/2012"

Comment: See my edit on replacing `DateTime.Parse` with `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: Date_Convert running properly... BUT Now I'm getting an exception from DB "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime"

Comment: As I said - in that case, you're either not passing a `DateTime` value to the SQL code, but a `string`. Show the code you're using to send the `DateTime` to the database and I can try to help you.

Comment: It is working fine in my local system. Hw it is possible without passing value.but not in my server

Comment: This may be the case if the server has different cultural settings than the local system. As I have asked before: *Please show the code that passes the value to the database!*

Answer (score 1):

Try [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) it receives as parameter the pattern so for your case it would be "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: when use this I'm getting an exception from db like "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime"       And the important thing is, it is working in my local system perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The format of the DataTime will depend on the current culture of your application. Inorder to have a specific format throught your application you can set the  tag in the web.config file under  section. In such case you need not write code to convert the datatime to proper format. By default all the dates will be set to the format specified.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1109183.aspx/1

**[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680598/problem-with-convert-todatetime-in-asp-net)**

Comment: Please explain in detail, actually I'm not using any culture related tags in my web.config, so that I mentioned it in the function it self.